# Place at infinity in function fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

I've just started reading about function fields.

If I understood it correctly, for a function field in one variable $F|K$ there is a correspondence between places (i.e., maximal ideal of a valuation ring $K \subsetneq O\subsetneq F$), discrete valuations and valuation rings.

But I don't understand what people mean by "place at infinity".

In the case of the rational function field $K(x)|K$, for example, what is the place at infinity? Which valuation ring is it associated to?

Comment: The valuation ring associated with the place at infinity consists of rational function such that the degree of the numerator is at most that of the denominator. Easy to check that such a beast forms a valuation ring. Another easy exercise is to show that this ring consists of rational functions defined at $t=0$, when written in terms of $t=1/x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function field $K(x)$ is the field of fractions of the affine domain $K[x]$.  Most places of $K(x)$ come from maximal ideals of $K[x]$ (i.e., the associated valuation ring is a localization of $K[x]$ at a maximal ideal).  However, there's one place that doesn't: namely, the place corresponding to the localization of $K[1/x]$ at the maximal ideal $(1/x)$.  This is called the "place at infinity".  One reason for this is that the associated valuation takes a rational function $f$ to the "order of vanishing of $f$ at $\infty$" (if the numerator of $f$ has degree $a$ and the denominator has degree $b$, that's $b-a$, which intuitively measures how fast $f(x)$ approaches $0$ as $x\to\infty$).

Another explanation for the name is geometrical.  You can think of $K(x)$ as the field of rational functions on the affine curve $\operatorname{Spec} K[x]=\mathbb{A}^1$.  All of the places except the place at $\infty$ correspond to closed points in this affine curve.  The place at $\infty$, however, corresponds only to a point in its completion $\mathbb{P}^1$, where it is the usual "point at $\infty$" in the projective line.

Similarly, if $F$ is any other function field that is the field of rational functions on some smooth affine curve $C$, then places of $F$ correspond to points in the completion of $C$.  The places that correspond to actual points of $C$ are "finite places", and the places that correspond only to points in the completion are "infinite places".

Note that this notion of "infinite place" is not intrinsic: it depends on a choice of affine domain that you view your function field as the field of fractions of.  For instance, if you consider $K(x)$ as the field of fractions of $K[1/x]$ instead of $K[x]$, then what used to be the infinite place is now a finite place.  This is in contrast to the case of number fields, where infinite places really are intrinsically different from other places.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph alone. The function field side is more democratic than the number field variant. With $F=K(x)$ we can move the infinite place around quite a bit by rewriting it $F=K(t)$ with $t=(ax+b)/(cx+d), ad-bc\neq0$.

Comment: Geometrically, what do you mean by  completion of $C$?

Comment: I mean a complete smooth curve that contains $C$ as an open subvariety.  You can construct it by taking the closure of $C$ in projective space and then normalizing.

Comment: one more question: how do we know that places coming from maximal ideals + place at $\infty$ comprehend all possible places?

Comment: That's a nontrivial theorem.  I don't remember how the proof goes off the top of my head.

Comment: Great answer. The idea in the last paragraph would have answered the recently deleted https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4259476/96384, assuming that the constant field $k$ was algebraically closed there i.e. all irreducible polynomials are of degree $1$.